# How to add exceptions to .htaccess redirect rule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm absolutely unknowledgeable of Apache `.htaccess` language and to be frank, I presently don't have time to look into it.

I have divided my website to following directories:

```
/My-Website
  /admin
  /public
```

To me, it seems like a good practice to separate the administration portal from the public website with distinctive folders. Admin is where the administration updates the contents and public is, well, public.

However, this way, I face two key problems:

1. I have somehow configured .htaccess to redirect all URLs to `/public` directory. But I want an exception to the `/admin` directory. Meaning that when the user enters `mywebsite.com`, it should redirect to `/public` automatically but not when the user enters `mywebsite.com/admin`. I'm not sure if .htaccess would have the solution or PHP, but am welcomed to both.
2. In my admin directory, I have JS files and other xml lying around in the admin directory. Did a test, found out that the users can access all the files in the admin directory by explicitly going to for example: `mywebsite.com/admin/may_be_sensitive.xml` without authorization. How can I tackle this?

I'm quite open to suggestions even if it means that I need to re-organize my entire website in a different structure.

Comment: Why is this tagged javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any redirection.

/public should be the root, so the public portion of your website would be visible at https://example.com

/admin should be a subdirectory off public (your webroot) like https://example.com/admin, and should be secured with an appropriate authentication process like basic auth, a one-time token or some other form of secure auth.

It's possible to secure the admin folder with a .htaccess file but it's more secure to do in the server configuration file if you have access to it.

From: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html

```
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/secret"> 
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords"
</Directory>
```

The password file is created with the htpasswd utility.